# Is there a GUI app to monitor remote load or memory use?

Tags: linux, remote, system-monitoring

I'm administering a set of Linux servers with varying purposes, and occasionally when I run maintenance tasks I'd like to see how each of the servers handles them. For this I need to open several terminals with `tload` running in each, and a couple more for `free -m` looping in a couple of boxes.

I'd like to know if there's a GUI app, preferably for OSX but other platforms work too, which could handle the data collection and render them into graphs so that I wouldn't need to open a lot of terminals? Optimally the app could be so light that I could use it in day-to-day monitoring, but this is handled by Munin already on a wider scale, so it's not a necessity.

Note: I'm not sure if this belongs here or on Server Fault, but since I'm looking for a client-side app, I thought I'd try here first.

Answer (score 3):

The data you want is often available through the [Simple Network Management Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snmp) (SNMP).

If an appropriate daemon is running on the target machine, you can connect to it and retrieve the data you're interested in. Appropriate daemon packages are:

- Ubuntu/Debian: snmpd
- CentOS/RHEL/Fedora: net-snmp-utils

You can read the data provided by those daemons with tools such as [snmpwalk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/snmpwalk.1.html). Most likely, that's not what you want though.

Other tools can also periodically fetch that data from the target machine and plot nice graphs from it. One of these tools is [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/index.php).

[image]

If Cacti is not for you, I completely understand :) Alternatives can be easily dug up search the web for **SNMP** and **RRDTool** (the tool that draws the graphs shown in the picture above).

Comment: I actually have Munin, which replaces my need for Cacti, but it's too broad for my needs. I'm looking for something with a 1-5sec refresh rate. I'll take a look at SNMP-based solutions, thanks for that info!

Answer (score 1):

The [gkrellm](http://freecode.com/projects/gkrellm) tool has a server mode that lets you view these stats on a remote machine. Run it it daemon mode on one machine, then connect to it using the GUI client.